# Ionic 2 and PouchDB : error 404 or 409 while updating a doc

Tags: ionic2, pouchdb

I'd like to update some docs using the put method of PouchDB database but it always fails with errors sometimes 404 or 409...

My docs are made as:

```
{
    "_id": "1",
    "id": 1,
    "type": "area",
    "translations": {
      "fr": "Frigo",
      "en": "Fridge"
    },
    "stats": {
      "totalProducts": 0,
      "totalQuantity": 0,
      "stockPrice": 0.00
    },
    "logo": "frigo.png"
}
```

And the process to update :

```
this._db.get('1', {include_docs: true}).then((doc) => {
    console.log('Original area : ' + JSON.stringify(doc));
    let updateDoc: any = {};
    updateDoc._id = doc._id;
    updateDoc._rev = doc._rev;
    updateDoc.stats.totalProducts = doc.stats.totalProducts++;
    updateDoc.stats.totalQuantity = doc.stats.totalQuantity + product.stock[0].initialQuantity;
    updateDoc.stats.stockPrice = doc.stats.stockPrice + product.stock[0].totalPrice;
    this._db.put(updateDoc).then((response) => {
      console.log('Update success');
    });
  }).catch(function(err){
    console.log('Exception raised : ' + err);
})
```

What am I doing wrong? I take care to set _id and _rev but I keep getting error code 404 or 409.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the documentation on [understanding revisions](https://pouchdb.com/guides/documents.html#understanding-revisions-rev) and especially on [updating documents correctly](https://pouchdb.com/guides/documents.html#updating-documents%E2%80%93correctly).

You cannot add a different document with the same `_id` and `_rev` again this will lead to the 409 conflict error (see also [the docs on put](https://pouchdb.com/api.html#create_document)). You have to change the original object instead:

```
this._db.get('1', {include_docs: true}).then((doc) => {
    console.log('Original area : ' + JSON.stringify(doc));

    doc.stats.totalProducts = doc.stats.totalProducts++;
    doc.stats.totalQuantity = doc.stats.totalQuantity + product.stock[0].initialQuantity;
    doc.stats.stockPrice = doc.stats.stockPrice + product.stock[0].totalPrice;
    this._db.put(doc).then((response) => {
       console.log('Update success');
    });
})
```

---

The 404 error indicates that the document you're trying to get does not exist (anymore). Make sure you haven't deleted the document you're trying to get and also make sure you're not trying to get the document, before it is created...

Comment: Thx... Will try this way... For others... with Ionic 2 and cordova-sqlite, you have to add to constructor 'location': 'default' :

Answer (score 0):

Okay, some troubles in my code, and if it helps...

First, replace constructor of PouchDB this way :

```
  PouchDB.plugin(cordovaSqlitePlugin);
  this._db = new PouchDB('easystock.db', { adapter: 'cordova-sqlite', location: 'default' });
```

Take care to add : location: 'default' if not, database is not created on the device.

Second issue, my PouchDB constructor was called in a specific method, so when i wanted to update my docs, the _db property was not set, then... refactor my service and move PouchDB instanciantion in the service constructor.

Finally, apply .get().then() as answered early...

Thx 4 all

JL

Answer (score 0):

PouchDB [upsert](https://github.com/pouchdb/upsert) provides a more convenient way to update a doc:

```
db.upsert('docID',function(doc){
    /* Modify "doc" as you wish */
    doc.whatever='new whatever'

    /* return doc after all modifications are done: */
    return doc;
})
```